# How to make an input focus like dogpile.com?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, focus

I want an `<input>` ([jsfiddle.net/cT9kg](http://jsfiddle.net/cT9kg/29/)) to behave exactly the same as on [dogpile.com](http://dogpile.com).

More specific the `<input>` should:

- have a predefined text inside it when is focused
- that text reappearing when user's input data is deleted and losing the focus

How is this done?

Answer (score 6):

By using the `placeholder` attribute which is supported in newest browsers:

> http://jsfiddle.net/cT9kg/30/

Comment: Fantastic! Just what i needed. I will top answer this when the time limit is up! Thanks again!

Comment: It's worth adding that support isn't universal (as @Tatu mentions), so you could provide a JavaScript fallback for those browsers that don't support it natively. Something like this (https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder) will do the job. It has the advantage of not polluting your HTML with JS code, and respecting competent browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [this tutorial from buildinternet.com](http://buildinternet.com/2009/01/changing-form-input-styles-on-focus-with-jquery/) many times - it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onfocus() {
        document.getElementById("box").setAttribute("value","");
    }
    function onblur() {
        if (document.getElementById("box").getAttribute("value") == "") {
            document.getElementById("box").setAttribute("value","Enter Something");
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="text" id="box" value="Enter Something" onfocus="Focus()" onblur="Blur()" />
```